# How to add top level column to the existing dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have to create dataframe, and to add three columns from existing one, but I need to add one more column, at the root level,so that other three be like this: root_column1, root_column2, root_column3.
I'm not sure how to do that in Python.

I have tried to google up, but didn't find anything useful.

I have spark code and I need to do the same in Python :

```
var newDataFrame  = existingDf.withColumn(rootColumn, struct(existingDf("column1"), existingDf("column2"), existingDf(column3)))
```

When I do head(df) I want the result to be :

```
rootColumnName_column1 rootColumnName_Column2 rootColumnName_Column3
 5 .                              7                        9
 12                               17                       19
```

Comment: Are you trying to add a multi index level, or are you just trying to add a column prefix?

Comment: When I look at the another schema it has one column(top level) and other columns are inside that column, and they have top level column name as prefix when I print the dataset. I just need to do like that.

Comment: `df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['root'], df.columns])`